# How to show event dots on FSCalendar in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

[How to Add events to FSCalendar Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874349/how-to-add-events-to-fscalendar-swift)

Hi there, I need proper flow for show are highlight the event dots on FSCalendar for Swift 4.

I have getting the date from API response.

Answer (score 0):

Theres almost no information to answer but follow the codes in link and
after getting dates from API response, reload the calendar